# Missing class from executable jar

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I have a maven project in which i need to upgrade the POM file to point to the latest versions of Java/spark/scala .But , when i am doing a clean , package from Intellij IDE , the no. of classes included in the executable jar are less than which get included using the old POM file(with old Java/Scala/Spark versions).

I am putting here the old & new POM both.

**OLD POM**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ABCExtracts</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABCExtracts</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11.8</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.3</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false
                </enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>


        <repository>
            <id>mapr-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>


    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.db</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprdb-spark</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1-mapr</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-tools/maven-scala-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId> <!-- matching Scala version -->
            <version>2.4.3</version>  <!-- matching Spark Core version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.5-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.5-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.5-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.5-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8-mapr-1710</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-native_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>3.5</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-jackson_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-ast_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- enable scalatest -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ################################################## -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>jcifs:jcifs</include>
                                    <include>com.itextpdf:itextpdf</include>
                                    <include>com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker</include>
                                    <!--          <include>org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11</include> -->
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

**NEW POM**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ABCExtracts</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABCExtracts</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.version>2.12.15</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12.15</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.version>3.2.0.0</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>


        <repository>
            <id>mapr-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bc-fips -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bc-fips</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.db</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprdb-spark_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ojai</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojai-scala</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-tools/maven-scala-plugin -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId> <!-- matching Scala version -->
            <version>3.2.0.3-eep-810</version>  <!-- matching Spark Core version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3-eep-810</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13.100-eep-800</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13.200-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13.200-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13.200-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13.200-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13.200-eep-810</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-crypto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalastyle/scalastyle-maven-plugin -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-native_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-ast_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>[2.13.2.1,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- enable scalatest -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- ################################################## -->



            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <!--args>
                        <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
                    </args-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>jcifs:jcifs</include>
                                    <include>com.itextpdf:itextpdf</include>
                                    <include>com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker</include>
                                    <!--          <include>org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11</include> -->
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Comment: And why should it be the same? Newer dependencies newer or different classes? Why is the number of classes important? Doesn't your application work? Doesn't it run? Do you get an error?

Comment: What exactly are the issues except having a different number of classes? Does it not run? What error do you get?

Comment: my jobs fail with a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error.

Comment: And which class is not found?

Comment: this is the error which i get : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.123.abc.common.CustomFunctions$ . This class is present at path src\main\scala\com\123\abc\common.

Comment: It would probably be better to [edit] your question and add the _full_ stack trace.

Comment: This looks like it is one of your classes, not from a dependency. Also the $ usually indicates a private nested class inside the actual class (CustomFunctions in this case). Generally that error can have multiple causes, from not being included in your build, to simply being removed but still referenced

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)